# Angular JS set dynamic value into ng-click directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to set value into ns-click dynamically, i mean that:

```
<td ng-click="{{schedule.action}}" ng-init="schedule.action=schedule.action" ng-repeat="schedule in room.Schedule">{{schedule.firstName}}</td>
```

i'm getting the following error message:

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{schedule.action}}] starting at [{schedule.action}}].

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You should have function call on ng-click instead of calling variable

Comment: Possible approach:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151543/how-to-dynamically-bind-function-to-ng-click-using-the-function-expression-from

Comment: schedule.action in this variable there is different value, but all values are function

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` directive will not interpolation directive `{{}}` in it, that will throw `$parser` exception. Basically it can have `function` call, or code dealing with scope variables.

**Markup**

```
<td ng-click="someMethod()" ng-init="schedule.action=schedule.action" 
  ng-repeat="schedule in room.Schedule">
    {{schedule.firstName}}
</td>
```

Comment: I know what u mean, but i use html table and i want to show different dialog, when user click at the different <td> (table cell). so i need dynamic parameter

Comment: @zuri you could use `ng-if` for showing and hiding div..you need to toggle flag to show hide the relevant div..

Comment: when i try that ng-click="reservationModal(schedule.currentDate)" in generated source i'm getting same string. schedule.currentDate value is not passed

Comment: @zuri could you give me plunkr..will help you more to solve your issue.

Comment: what do you mean in "plunkr" ?

Comment: @zuri It means the runnalbe code with problem you are facing http://plnkr.co/edit/LEDDI0TX6OvKj0gNJrSl?p=preview

Comment: i could not attach my code in plnkr, because it is big project so it contains to much files.